# How can I display numbers like 2 over 2, but not have them as fractions?

Tags: fractions

I want to show how to simplify a fraction. Something like simplyfy 27/18 by dividing the top and bottom by 9. But I don't want to show the 9 on the top and bottom as the fraction 9/9. Is there a way?

Comment: What have you tried? What do you want, in a quick sketch?

Comment: Also, how do you want the stack aligned, vertically, and horizontally?

Comment: With amsmath, you can use the genfrac command, as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80497/107497

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\divby[1]{%
  \setstackgap{L}{1.1\baselineskip}%
  \renewcommand\stacktype{L}%
  \stackanchor{\div#1}{\div#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\[
\frac{27}{18}\divby{9} = \frac{3}{2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With not too prominent divisors:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\newcommand{\fracdiv}[3]{%
  \frac{#1\mathrlap{\scriptstyle\div#3}}
       {#2\mathrlap{\scriptstyle\div#3}}%
  \hphantom{\scriptstyle\div#3}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\fracdiv{27}{18}{9}=\frac{3}{2}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]